# Почему std::plus не является вызываемым?

Tags: c++

Почему `std::plus<int>` не является вызываемым?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>


int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_invocable_r_v<int, std::plus<int>> << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Вы проверяете вызываемость без параметров. Попробуйте `std::is_invocable_r_v<int, std::plus<int>, int, int>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо, оформите в виде ответа -- я приму

Answer (score 2):

`std::is_invocable_r_v<>` проверяет результат вызова с конкретными типами параметров, а не впринципе возможность вызова. Поэтому правильный вызов для функционального объекта с 2 параметрами будет `std::is_invocable_r_v<int, std::plus<int>, int, int>`.